# MVC Rendering incorrectly with specific CSS selectors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, css-selectors

I am currently working on a project using C#.NET MVC (Razor).

I have come across a problem where text output is rendered differently if it is inside an html block with a css selector using a very specific name. No one here can tell me how or why.

Consider this, where @item.UserText = "Memo (Multiline Box)":

```
<div class="form-element-title">@item.UserText</div>
```

Which renders extra whitespace:

```
<div class="form-element-title">  Memo (  Multiline   Box)</div>
```

Rename the css class to anything else other than "form-element-title":

```
<div class="form-element-label">@item.UserText</div>
```

And it renders as expected:

```
<div class="form-element-label">Memo (Multiline Box)</div>
```

There are no introduced or inherited attributes in the css when inspecting the broken rendered document.

It would appear MVC is using "form-element-title" in some other way and producing this whitespace at server.

This has me worried. Is this a reserved word? Are there more? Will other css names break layout in other cases?

Does anyone know what MVC is doing here or why?

---

I have not been able to replicate this with a new project.

I have created a new project adding small chunks at a time, and am not seeing the issue.

I now have a full project that for all intents and purposes is the same as the original, but with no problems.

The old project still shows the issue as described.

Could this be a bug in the old project file itself?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at this line in the view.. what does `item.UserText` contain before it is rendered?

Comment: I just tested this, and I'm not getting the same result. My suggestion would be to load up the page with the incorrect looking text, then right click and inspect element (in firefox with firebug or chrome), and see if there are any styles being loaded. That said, does it happen if you remove all stylesheets from the page?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting the same result either and this isn't how razor works anyway. Check your css first. See if you can reproduce this yourself in a vanilla project. If you can then it's a bug.

Comment: How are you observing this rendered output?  Are you doing View->Source?  Or are you looking in a Developer tools window or what?

Comment: Thanks for the very quick replies.
  
I have been viewing source (right click menu) and using Chrome Dev Tools. I have checked and removed all css and the problem still occurs.
  
Alarmingly, I started a new blank project and added *only* the offending code and am *not* seeing the problem. 
  
I then recreated the project to what I am certain is the same as the original project, and am again *not* seeing the problem.
  
I have now renamed everything back to "form-element-title" and am again *not* seeing the problem.
  
This must be some weird bug with the old project file? We are stumped...